# Calculated fields in SELECT statement in ABAP

Tags: select, abap

Does ABAP support calculated fields in SELECT statement? Such as:

```
SELECT price quantity price*quantity AS sum
FROM ...
INTO ...
WHERE ...
```

If not, let advanced coders tell me what solutions they use to cope with this task.
Do not offer such performance decreasing ways as calculation into temporary variable within SELECT cycle.

```
SELECT.
...
ENDSELECT.
```

Comment: Rene beat me to it. What he proposes is what 'advanced coders' do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open SQL only supports a couple of aggregate functions. Calculations should be done in memory, after selecting the records and saving the result into an internal table.
So in short:

```
select ... into table itab from ...
loop at itab assigning <itab_row>.
  " Perform calculations on row here
endloop.
```